# Extracting start and end points from OSM Segment using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm very new to gis. I have osm layer shape file. How can can I extract start and end points of segments and add points id to the attribute table osm segment?

Comment: Better if you can share a sample of your shape file

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works